# Eclipse type hierarchy stack overflow

Tags: java, eclipse

I am repeatedly getting stack overflow errors on eclipse. It corresponds to adding Apache's PDFBox 2.0 to my build path and incorporating and modifying some code I found on SO. [This eclipse bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=476933) seems pertinent. 
   I have tried refreshing, closing and reopening the project, deleting the .index files etc.
Here is the eclipse log:

```
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.recommenders.utils.Logs$LogTraceException
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.utils.Logs$LogTraceException.newTrace(Logs.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.utils.Logs.log(Logs.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.internal.types.rcp.ProjectTypesIndex.needsRebuild(ProjectTypesIndex.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.internal.types.rcp.ProjectTypesIndex.startUp(ProjectTypesIndex.java:122)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$2$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:54)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$3.run(Callables.java:93)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2017-03-31 14:07:44.593
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Indexing type hierarchy of project ‘penelope-vision’".
!STACK 0
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
    at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:556)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.hierarchy.TypeHierarchy.getAllSupertypes0(TypeHierarchy.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.hierarchy.TypeHierarchy.getAllSupertypes0(TypeHierarchy.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.hierarchy.TypeHierarchy.getAllSupertypes0(TypeHierarchy.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.hierarchy.TypeHierarchy.getAllSupertypes0(TypeHierarchy.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.hierarchy.TypeHierarchy.getAllSupertypes0(TypeHierarchy.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.hierarchy.TypeHierarchy.getAllSupertypes0(TypeHierarchy.java:522)
```

The last line is repeated many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is an acknowledged bug by Eclipse community, you can take the following workarounds:

1) Try to use a newer version of Eclipse (Oxygen or Neon).

2) Backup your projects from the workspace. Delete your workspace. Start Eclipse and let it create a new one. Then copy over your projects from backup to the new workspace.

Comment: I'm already on Neon, the workspace deleting seemed to do the trick though, at least hasn't happened since then.